# How To Set Headers For DeleteAsync

Tags: c#, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to set custom headers on a HttpClient.DeleteAsync request.  I've tried using

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id",ParseAppID);
```

but get this error

```
Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.
```

HttpClient.SendAsync can send custom request headers with

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id",ParseAppID);
```

and HttpClient.PostAsync can send them with

```
System.Net.Http.StringContent.Headers.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id",ParseAppID);
```

How can I do this with DeleteAsync?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. The code [here](https://gist.github.com/mattwcole/5124b49cd9efec4bd7eb) works without issue for me. Did you get to the bottom of it?

Answer (score 4):

Instantiate an `HttpRequestMessage` and use `SendAsync` instead:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Delete, requestUri);
request.Headers.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id", ParseAppID);

using (var response = await _calendarClient.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
{
    if (response.StatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.NotFound))
    {
        return;
    }
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}
```

Comment: Such a bummer that I cannot do that with httpclient()

Comment: `calendarClient` _is_ an `HttpClient`.